# Extract the Version number from the output using regex python?

Tags: python, regex

I want the version number from the output and for both the output I want one code only

> Edition: Read the output starts with Cisco till Version then extract the Version Number
>
> For example:Read the line like this Cisco IOS Software, s2t54 Software (s2t54-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.5(1)SY2, 
>   the ouput Version
>
> Output : 15.5(1)SY2
>
> Output 1:
>   '''
>   Cisco IOS Software, s2t54 Software (s2t54-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.5(1)SY2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc6)
>   ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(50r)SYS3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
>   CPU: MPC8572_E, Version: 2.2, (0x80E80022)
>   CORE: E500, Version: 3.0, (0x80210030)
>   '''
>
> Output 2:
>   Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch  Software (cat4500es8-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.08.07.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
>   licensed under the GNU General Public License ("GPL") Version 2.0.  The
>   software code licensed under GPL Version 2.0 is free software that comes
>   GPL code under the terms of GPL Version 2.0.

I tried ths code:

```
r = re.findall(r'Version\s*(([\w]+))', str)
r[0]
```

it gives output:

> 15.5
>
> 03.08.07.E

expected output:

> 15.5(1)SY2
>
> 03.08.07.E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Version\s+([^,\s]+).+`

Explanation:

`Version` - matches `Version` literally

`\s+` - matches one or more of white spaces

`([^,\s]+)` - match one or more characters other from whitespace `\s` or comma `,` and store it inside first capturing group

`.+` - match one or more of any characters (except newline), this is to consume rest of the output and prevent from matching multiple versions in one output

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sqh3Ph/2)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the expression you are looking for:

```
Version\s*(.+?)[\s|,]
```

It matches anything after "Version" until it finds a comma or a blank space

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is;

a = r'Version\s*(.+?)[\s|,|[]'

example output:

6.4.2

03.06.06E

03.16.07b.S

12.0(18b)

12.2(33.3.8)SB13

12.2(33)SXI2a